# Take sub-averages and create a new column with their classification

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset more or less like this:

```
place_id   person_id   amount
A          Huey        20
A          Louie       30
A          Dewey       40
B          Huey        80
B          Dewey       100
C          Louie       500
```

Let's say the place is a restaurant and I want to calculate the per-capita spending on each place, adding it as a new column:

```
place_id   person_id   amount   pc_spend
A          Huey        20       30
A          Louie       30       30
A          Dewey       40       30
B          Huey        80       90
B          Dewey       100      90
C          Louie       500      500
```

I know how to calculate the pc spend in R using aggregate(), but I don't know how to feed the calculation back to each line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(place_id) %>% mutate(pc_spend = mean(amount) )
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: place_id

  place_id person_id amount pc_spend
1        A      Huey     20       30
2        A     Louie     30       30
3        A     Dewey     40       30
4        B      Huey     80       90
5        B     Dewey    100       90
6        C     Louie    500      500
```

Here is my (a little clumsy I admit it) solution in base R;

```
pc_spend <- tapply(df$amount, df$place_id, mean)
df[df$"place_id" == "A" , "pc_spend"] <- pc_spend[1]
df[df$"place_id" == "B" , "pc_spend"] <- pc_spend[2]
df[df$"place_id" == "C" , "pc_spend"] <- pc_spend[3]
df
  place_id person_id amount pc_spend
1        A      Huey     20       30
2        A     Louie     30       30
3        A     Dewey     40       30
4        B      Huey     80       90
5        B     Dewey    100       90
6        C     Louie    500      500
```